# Out-File only printing half of my results

Tags: powershell, csv, split, save

I currently have a CSV file that has 2,440 lines of data. The data looks something like:

```
server1:NT:Y:N:N:00:N
server2:NT:Y:N:n:33:N
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$newCsvPath = Get-Content .\sever.csv |
              Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^#|^$|^"#' } 

[int]$windows = 0
[int]$totalsever = 0
$Results = @()

$date = Get-Date -Format g

Clear-Content .\results.csv -Force

foreach ($thing in $newCsvPath) {
    $totalsever++
    $split = $thing -split ":"
    if ($split[1] -contains "NT") { 
        $windows++
        $thing | Out-File results.csv -Append -Force
    } else {
        continue
    }
}

Clear-Content .\real.csv -Force
$servers = Get-Content results.csv
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $server.Split(':')[0] | Out-File real.csv -Append -Force
}
```

My issue is that when the script gets to the `$server.Split(':')[0] | Out-File real.csv -Append -Force` part, for some reason it only outputs 1,264 lines instead of all 2,440 to "real.csv". However, when I remove `| Out-File real.csv -Append -Force`, `$server` stores ALL 2,400 names of servers.

Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Change `split[1] -contains "NT"` into 'split[1] -eq "NT"`. Strange way of handling csv though.. Why not use `Import-CSV -Delimiter ':'` and work with the object?

Comment: Why don't you output `$split[0]` in the same if as `$thing` directly to `real.csv`? The second get-content,foreach is superfluous.

Comment: I agree that it is a strange way to do this, but my issue is the file itself. If I use `Import-CSV`, it keeps thinking the comments are the headers, and throws off the rest of the file regardless of the fact that I skip those lines.

I also can't use `$split[0] | Out-File results.csv -Append -Force`, because it keeps printing out 1,264 lines instead of all 2,400, which is the main issue I'm having.